# facebook API - how to search public status

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i can search user, event, page, etc refered to [FB API DOC](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion)

and i can search my own feed/status

but i cant search public status, like "who is update status about football today" like i did in Twitter API.

So, my question is : How to search public status using facebook graph api?

if this not possible, can i search feed from my friend (at least) ?

Im use PHP SDK, Facebook graph API v2.8

Comment: You can not search for public posts via API. (There is the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/), but access to that is limited to special FB partners.) And if you want to read a friend’s posts, then that friend needs to login to your app and grant it permission to read their posts first.

Comment: they need only login once or need login every several times?

Comment: You'll have to check if the app access token still allows reading a user's posts if they granted the app the permission. (Used to be the case, but I haven't checked lately.)

Comment: ok ill check it later. because now i starting youtube API. thanks for your help. its helpfull for me